# How to install a VMware Player computer that uses english?

Tags: windows-7, vmware

I started a VMware player visualization with my windows 7 disk, and it auto selected "Espanhol (Estados Unidos)" as the language, instead of English. When I went into the control panel to change this I cannot seem to find the option to change the language to English. Does anyone know where or how to change this as I cannot speak any Spanish.

Comment: Control Panel > Accessibility - I think.. You should be able to just screw around for a while til you find it.

Comment: So far i have not found it. :(

Comment: Maybe you should grow up and just learn Spanish. ;)

Comment: I would but i don't want to wait at least 2 weeks. :P

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have a guide on doing that here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-display-language

The instructions will apply to Windows 7 too. What I'd do is look at the Google Translated version and pay attention the text in bold to find out what the relevant icons and menu items will be named in the Spanish version of windows:
[Google translated version from English to Spanish](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=es&u=http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-display-language)

Comment: Ok so i did that but after i clicked Armenio and apply nothing changed? i also tryed some other ones but none of the words on anything have changed.

Comment: Try changing the system locale too: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-system-locale

Comment: Hmm, i just did that and it keeps changing back. I select the right one and then it asks me to restart and when it logs back on it's the same as before.

Comment: Is the Language Bar enabled, are there any options there?

Comment: If you mean the thing that is at the top of the screen that shows you what your typing in, yes. But i can't read what it says.

Comment: By any chance have you set your VMWare to have a persistent image? Do any changes stay upon reboot?

Comment: changes do stay i think, i have some programs installed and have edited some stuff.

Comment: When you say you cannot read it, is it illegible or in Spanish?

Comment: It looks like illegible but it just Spanish.